# Why does deny roles not work in membership?

Tags: asp.net

```
<location path="MoviesReview.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny roles="Users"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

I am not able to restrict roles of users to this movies page.What could be the problem?

Comment: It looks right, did you configure role manager also?

Comment: can you add more detail? how about posting your code to get the roles?

Comment: what do I have to do with rolemanager

Comment: you need to set enable = true for roleManager element in your application's web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh It worked! I hadnt set the role for the users! It's proper now.